# What is the purpose of the instruction fldz on the Aaron Adams shellcode?

Tags: shellcode, assembly

I'm studying the Aaron Adams assembly code. You can find the documentation [here](http://phrack.org/issues/62/7.html) (section --[ 2.b.i Getting EIP).

I understand that the goal is to get the EIP.

I know that the FPU environment looks like below:

```
struct _fpstate_32 {
/* Legacy FPU environment: */
__u32                cw;
__u32                sw;
__u32                tag;
__u32                ipoff;
__u32                cssel;
__u32                dataoff;
__u32                datasel;
```

And `ipoff` contains the EIP.

So the `fnstenv [esp-12]` puts `cw`,`sw`,`tag` and `ipoff` on the stack and then I can get the EIP on ECX with `pop ecx`.

But I don't understand the purpose of `fldz`.

`fldz` "Push +0.0 onto the FPU register stack". It means we have a second stack on the FPU? And why do we need to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, the value of `EIP` that you've mentionned (`ipoff`) is actually the value taken from the `Last instruction pointer` register.

Therefore, when calling `fnstenv [esp-12]`, the value that will be pushed on the stack will be a pointer to the `fldz` instruction, since its the *last* floating point instruction to be executed before calling `fnstenv`.

Without it, the value returned by `fnstenv` could be anything.

Reference : https://home.deec.uc.pt/~jlobo/tc/artofasm/ch14/ch143.htm

> The instruction and data pointer registers contain certain state information about the last floating point instruction executed.